# Versioning API in Elixir Plug

Tags: elixir, plug

I have two modules: lib/endpoints/v1/base.ex and lib/endpoints/v2/base.ex.

**lib/endpoints/v1/base.ex**

```elixir
defmodule Http.Endpoints.V1.Base do
  require Logger
  use Plug.Router

  plug(:match)
  plug(:dispatch)
  plug(Plug.Logger)
  plug(Plug.Parsers, parsers: [:json], json_decoder: Poison)

  get "/v1/ping" do
    send_resp(conn, 200, "pong!")
  end
end
```

**lib/endpoints/v2/base.ex**

```elixir
defmodule Http.Endpoints.V2.Base do
  require Logger
  use Plug.Router

  plug(:match)
  plug(:dispatch)
  plug(Plug.Logger)
  plug(Plug.Parsers, parsers: [:json], json_decoder: Poison)

  get "/v2/ping" do
    send_resp(conn, 200, "pong! 2")
  end
end
```

My endpoint works correctly if I put in my applications.ex the children

`Plug.Cowboy.child_spec(scheme: :http, plug: Http.Endpoints.V1.Base, options: [port: Application.get_env(:http, :port)])`

But I would like my application starts all endpoints versions.

I tried to create lib/endpoints.ex with `require Http.Endpoints.V1.Base` and `require Http.Endpoints.V2.Base` and changed my applications.ex but it did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can forward to other routers from your endpoints file. Here is the documentation for the `forward/2` function: https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Router.html#forward/2

Basically you create 2 routers for v1 & v2:

```elixir
defmodule MyAppWeb.V2.Router do
  use Plug.Router

  plug :match
  plug :dispatch

  get "/ping" do
    send_resp(conn, 200, "OK")
  end
end
```

and

```elixir
defmodule MyAppWeb.V1.Router do
  use Plug.Router

  plug :match
  plug :dispatch

  get "/ping" do
    send_resp(conn, 200, "OK")
  end
end
```

Then in your endpoint you can add all the common functionality and forward to your versioned routes like so:

```elixir
defmodule MyAppWeb.Endpoint do
  require Logger
  use Plug.Router

  plug :match
  plug :dispatch
  plug Plug.Logger
  plug Plug.Parsers, parsers: [:json], json_decoder: Poison

  # Forwarding
  forward "/v2", to: MyApp.V2.Router
  forward "/v1", to: MyApp.V1.Router

  # You should put a catch-all here
  match _ do
    send_resp(conn, 404, "Not Found")
  end
end
```

Then in your `application.ex` file, mount your endpoint as you did before. However, at this point you should be able to ping both `/v1/ping` and `/v2/ping` from the same port.

Cheers!

Comment: Don't we have to match and dispatch on the sub-routers as well?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that it's required, but I remember having to do that in the past.

Comment: I just tried and it's definitely needed. The code compiles as `Plug.Router` exposes `init/1` and `call/2`, but if we don't add `:match` and `:dispatch` in the pipeline of the sub-routers, the connection will hang or simply fail (because it won't be passed to the paths configured in the router module). I'm adding them to the answer to save some time from people trying this.

Answer (score 1):

> My endpoint works correctly if I put in my applications.ex the
>   children
>
> ```
> Plug.Cowboy.child_spec(
>    scheme: :http, 
>    plug: Http.Endpoints.V1.Base, 
>    options: [port: Application.get_env(:http, :port)]
> )
> ```

The modern way to specify that is:

```
{Plug.Cowboy, [[ 
      scheme: :http, 
      plug: Http.Endpoints.V1.Base, 
      options: [port: Application.get_env(:http, :port)]
    ]]
}
```

See: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#module-child_spec-1

Although, to me it seems easier to call `child_spec()` directly, rather than try to figure how many brackets you need around the argument.